# Testing navigation with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I want to test if a sidebar that I have created for navigation works or not, this is a simple example of what I have made

```
<ul>
  <li><Link to="/location1">location 1</Link></li>
  <li><Link to="/location2">location 2</Link></li>
</ul>
```

this is my test

```
const routerWrapper = ({children}) => <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>

// The first one runs fine
it('navigation to location 1' , () => {
render(<SideBar/> , {wrapper:routerWrapper})
// get the element and click on it
// check if title of page is correct
})

it('navigation to location 2' , () => {
render(<SideBar/> , {wrapper:routerWrapper})
// can't run because location is at /location1
})
```

When I test the navigation with RTL, first test runs fine, but after that the location remains at that directory for next test, how do I clear location after every test? or any suggestions how should I test navigation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I did figure it out, we can use `<MemoryRouter>` for this purpose.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#memoryrouter

Just passed the value ['/'] to `initialEntries` prop from `<MemoryRouter>` and tests work fine.

also [slideshowp2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71013688/16585459)
is very useful if you are interested

Comment: but `/` is the value by default, and it does not navigate yet.

Comment: link updated: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router

Answer (score 8):

From the [Checking location in tests](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/guides/testing/checking-location-in-tests) doc:

> 1. You can also use BrowserRouter if your test environment has the browser globals `window.location` and `window.history` (which is the default in Jest through JSDOM, but you cannot reset the history between tests).

> 2. Instead of passing a custom route to MemoryRouter, you can use the base Router with a history prop from the history package

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export function SideBar() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/location1">location 1</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/location2">location 2</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { SideBar } from './';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

const createRouterWrapper = (history): React.ComponentType => ({ children }) => (
  <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
);

describe('SideBar', () => {
  it('navigation to location 1', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    render(<SideBar />, { wrapper: createRouterWrapper(history) });
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('location 1'));
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/location1');
  });

  it('navigation to location 2', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    render(<SideBar />, { wrapper: createRouterWrapper(history) });
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('location 2'));
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/location2');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/70974339/index.test.tsx (8.701 s)
  SideBar
    ✓ navigation to location 1 (40 ms)
    ✓ navigation to location 2 (4 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.232 s
```

Comment: Actually I didn't know about <MemoryRouter> when I asked this, I ended up using that. but this also seems to be a good way to do it. thanks

Comment: I get `Property 'location' does not exist on type 'History'.`

Answer (score 2):

I had troubles to implemented the accepted answer.

The following solution will not check directly for a path being opened, but for the component that should be rendered at that path.

```
describe('SideBar', () => {
  it('navigation to location 1', () => {
    // setup
    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialIndex={0} initialEntries={['/testbase']}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/testbase" element={<Sidebar/>}/>
            <Route path="/location1" element={<div>location 1</div>} />
          </Routes>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    // run 
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('location 1'));

    // check
    expect(screen.getByText('location 1')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Notes:

- `initialEntries` provides a history that can be accessed.
- `initialIndex` tells the router which route of `initialEntries` should be opened first (in this case */testbase*.

OT Notes:

- It's probably a good idea to wrap fireEvent in *act* and use await. (to prevent test failing once the component becomes more sophisticated)
- It might be a good idea to wrap render in *act* and use await (to prevent test failing once the component becomes more sophisticated)

### Encapsulate MemoryRouter

If you'd like to encapsulate MemoryRouter to make the tests more concise, here's an idea (in Typescript):

```
import React from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

export type Route = {
  path: string;
  element: React.ReactElement;
}

export type TestRouterProps = {
  initialRoute?: string;
  routes: Route[];
};

/**
 *
 * How to use: 
 *       <TestRouter initialRoute="/testbase"
 *          routes={[
 *            { path: '/testbase', element: <MyComponent/> },
 *            { path: '/', element: <div>aaa</div> },
 *          ]}
 *       />
 *
 **/
export const TestRouter: React.FC<TestRouterProps> = (props: TestRouterProps) => {

  const routerProps = props.initialRoute ? {
    initialIndex: 0,
    initialEntries: [props.initialRoute],
  } : {};

  return (
  <MemoryRouter {...routerProps}>
    <Routes>
      {props.routes.map((route) => <Route path={route.path} element={route.element} />)}
    </Routes>
  </MemoryRouter>);
}
```